# Someone can help me with thist issued: Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below)

Tags: contract-deployment, chainlink, gas-estimate

Some one can help me to solve this issue, I'm student and I try to deploy a Smart Contract for a practic, I must Deploy 3 contract, When I Try to deploy the last one it show me an error "Gas Estimation Error", I let you the 3 contract here, and let the link That I found in Gibhub.com with whole code: "https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.6.6+commit.6c089d02.js&optimize=false&gist=1bb62664cfad04de04d9dc5d059eb519"

Governance Contract

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

contract Governance {
    uint256 public one_time;
    address public lottery;
    address public randomness;
    constructor() public {
        one_time = 1;
    }
    function init(address _lottery, address _randomness) public {
        require(_randomness != address(0), "governance/no-randomnesss-address");
        require(_lottery != address(0), "no-lottery-address-given");
        //require(one_time > 0, "can-only-be-called-once");
        //one_time = one_time - 1;
        randomness = _randomness;
        lottery = _lottery;
    }
}
```

randomness contract

---

```
contract Randomness is VRFConsumerBase {
    
    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 internal fee;
    mapping (uint => uint) public randomNumber;
    mapping (bytes32 => uint) public requestIds;
    GovernanceInterface public governance;
    uint256 public most_recent_random;
    
    /**
     * Constructor inherits VRFConsumerBase
     * 
     * Network: Ropsten
     * Chainlink VRF Coordinator address: 0xf720CF1B963e0e7bE9F58fd471EFa67e7bF00cfb
     * LINK token address:                0x20fE562d797A42Dcb3399062AE9546cd06f63280
     * Key Hash: 0xced103054e349b8dfb51352f0f8fa9b5d20dde3d06f9f43cb2b85bc64b238205
     */
    constructor(address _governance) 
        VRFConsumerBase(
            0xf720CF1B963e0e7bE9F58fd471EFa67e7bF00cfb, // VRF Coordinator
            0x20fE562d797A42Dcb3399062AE9546cd06f63280  // LINK Token
        ) public
    {
        keyHash = 0xced103054e349b8dfb51352f0f8fa9b5d20dde3d06f9f43cb2b85bc64b238205;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
        governance = GovernanceInterface(_governance);
    }

    /** 
     * Requests randomness from a user-provided seed
     */
     
    function getRandom(uint256 userProvidedSeed, uint256 lotteryId) public {
        require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) > fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
        bytes32 _requestId = requestRandomness(keyHash, fee, userProvidedSeed);
        requestIds[_requestId] = lotteryId;
    }

    /**
     * Callback function used by VRF Coordinator
     */
    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) external override {
        require(msg.sender == vrfCoordinator, "Fulillment only permitted by Coordinator");
        most_recent_random = randomness;
        uint lotteryId = requestIds[requestId];
        randomNumber[lotteryId] = randomness;
        LotteryInterface(governance.lottery()).fulfill_random(randomness);
    }
}
```

Lottery Contract

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;
import "github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import {RandomnessInterface} from "./RandomnessInterface.sol";
import {GovernanceInterface} from "./GovernanceInterface.sol";

contract Lottery is ChainlinkClient {
    enum LOTTERY_STATE { OPEN, CLOSED, CALCULATING_WINNER }
    LOTTERY_STATE public lottery_state;
    uint256 public lotteryId;
    address payable[] public players;
    GovernanceInterface public governance;
    // .01 ETH
    uint256 public MINIMUM = 1000000000000000;
    // 0.1 LINK
    uint256 public ORACLE_PAYMENT = 300000000000000000;
    // Alarm stuff
    address CHAINLINK_ALARM_ORACLE = 0xc99B3D447826532722E41bc36e644ba3479E4365;
    bytes32 CHAINLINK_ALARM_JOB_ID = "2ebb1c1a4b1e4229adac24ee0b5f784f";
    
    constructor(address _governance) public
    {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        lotteryId = 1;
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
        governance = GovernanceInterface(_governance);
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        assert(msg.value == MINIMUM);
        assert(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    } 
    
  function start_new_lottery(uint256 duration) public {
    require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED, "can't start a new lottery yet");
    lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(CHAINLINK_ALARM_JOB_ID, address(this), this.fulfill_alarm.selector);
    req.addUint("until", now + duration);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(CHAINLINK_ALARM_ORACLE, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }
  
  function fulfill_alarm(bytes32 _requestId)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
      {
        require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN, "The lottery hasn't even started!");
        // add a require here so that only the oracle contract can
        // call the fulfill alarm method
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER;
        lotteryId = lotteryId + 1;
        pickWinner();
    }


    function pickWinner() private {
        require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER, "You aren't at that stage yet!");
        RandomnessInterface(governance.randomness()).getRandom(lotteryId, lotteryId);
        //this kicks off the request and returns through fulfill_random
    }
    
    function fulfill_random(uint256 randomness) external {
        require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER, "You aren't at that stage yet!");
        require(randomness > 0, "random-not-found");
        // assert(msg.sender == governance.randomness());
        uint256 index = randomness % players.length;
        players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
        players = new address payable[](0);
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
        // You could have this run forever
        // start_new_lottery();
        // or with a cron job from a chainlink node would allow you to 
        // keep calling "start_new_lottery" as well
    }

    function get_players() public view returns (address payable[] memory) {
        return players;
    }
    
    function get_pot() public view returns(uint256){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems there's some error with the code formatting. It would be great if you could update the code formatting and also mention how you tried deploying.
This would help provide context and enable people to help you. Please mention he order in which you tried to deploy the contracts too! Thanks.

Comment: Hi Willy, can you format your codes so that we can see what you are trying to achieve.